# Reading serial data from arduino with c# application

Tags: c#, serial-port, arduino

I am building a c# application that needs to read some serial data received from an arduino. The arduino sends the following:

```
Serial.write(0x1);
Serial.write(0x106);
Serial.write(fake_channel.samples, SAMPLE_COUNT); //Sample array
```

The sample array is nothing else than an array filled with integers.

What is the best way to read this with an c# application? I need to get the integer from the serial data. So when I got 0x1, I want to read the 1. I am able to read data with the following method:

```
private void serialPort_DataReceived(object sender, System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    //Code to read the serial data needed here

}
```

In an older application of mine, I was able to read some serial data in string format with: serialPort.ReadExisting();
The only problem now is that I am not receiving a string, but an integer that looks like a byte. That is the part I am confused about because how is it possible to read an integer out of a thing that looks like a byte.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `DataReceived` event tells you that some bytes were received and you can go and read them.

If you want to read bytes (not strings) you can use `serialPort.BytesToRead` property to know how many bytes are available to read. You can then use `serialPort.Read(byte[], int, int)` method to read all bytes at once, or `serialPort.ReadByte()` method to read one byte at a time.

If you try to read more bytes that the ones available the the method will block until the specified number of bytes are available. To prevent this you can set a read timeout using `serialPort.ReadTimeout`.

Comment: Only one question still left, what if the serialPort buffer reads its max?

Comment: If you let the buffer fill, you will lose all subsequent bytes.